# logistic_sgd module, where to find it?

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

doing a deep learning tutorial and my python cannot find that module.

```
from logistic_sgd import LogisticRegression, load_data
ImportError: No module named logistic_sgd
```

How can i install it ?

Answer (score 6):

Download and Save logistic_sgd.py from the following link:

http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py

Store it in the working directory. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should download all the code from the following link, it contains all the dependencies you need. 
Here is the source code:
http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

To download all the code necessary, you can go to GitHub.

Citing from: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/

> The code is available on the [Deep Learning Tutorial repositories](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials).

If you aren't familiar with Git, you can download the source code in one zip archive file from there.

Answer (score -1):

are you using the Theano library, if you are, that means your project cannot find the Theano library, use

```
sys.path.append(r'~/TheanoDL')
```

to declare it at the beginning of your project, change the path of it with your Theano is in.

Note that it works for a project with a customed Theano library.(my situation)

Best luck!